# PHP / AJAX function refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem with my function.
I want to refresh this function every 5 sec without refresh the page!

This is on refresh.php:

> ```
> if ($files_count == 0) {         
>         ?>       
>     <img src="img/upload.gif">                 
>     <?php    
>    }
> ```

and this is on index.php:

> ```
> <?php include 'refresh.php'; ?>
> ```

How to do it? :D

EDIT:

Comment: You realize that PHP runs on the server? there is no way you can "refresh" a function like this using server-side code. You'd need javascsript on the client for such a thing.

Comment: You're going to have to think this through a little more, because you can't repeat a PHP function with Javascript. Give me 5 minutes and I'll show you how to use jQuery and a real AJAX call back to a PHP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
setInterval(function(){check_files();}, 5000);

function check_files() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'path/to/php/file.php',
      type: 'GET',
      cache: false,
      data: {},
      success: function (resp) {
         if (resp == 0) {
            $('.container').html('<img src="img/upload.gif" />');
         }
         else {
            /// Something else
         }
      }
   });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$count = count(glob("your_directory/*",GLOB_BRACE)); // This is what I assume you're counting files with. You may be counting from a database, though. 

echo $count; // This goes back to the AJAX call.
```

Comment: resp does nothing... Why ? :S
I tested the php and its send me "1" but resp don't receives nothing

Comment: Because you have to set the glob counter to the directory, IF that's what you're using. You are responsible for how `$count` is come up with. I have no idea what the application is.

Comment: $filescount = $users->get_filesusercount($userid);
$files_count  = count($filescount);
Im using this... Im using mysql

Comment: Then replace my line with that and change `$files_count` to `$count`

Comment: I need more information than that. Can you do a browser debug?